# How to go to following link from a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape a website I am in a loop where every item have link I want to go to following every time in a loop.

```
import scrapy

class MyDomainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'My_Domain'
    allowed_domains = ['MyDomain.com']
    start_urls = ['https://example.com'] 

    def parse(self, response):
        Colums = response.xpath('//*[@id="tab-5"]/ul/li')
        for colom in Colums:
            title = colom.xpath('//*[@class="lng_cont_name"]/text()').extract_first()  
            address = colom.xpath('//*[@class="adWidth cont_sw_addr"]/text()').extract_first()
            con_address = address[9:-9]  
            url= colom.xpath('//*[@id="tab-5"]/ul/li/@data-href').extract_first() 
            print(url)
            print('*********************')    
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback = self.parse_dir_contents)


    def parse_dir_contents(self, response):
        print('000000000000000000')
        a = response.xpath('//*[@class="fn"]/text()').extract_first()   

        print(a)
```

I have tried something like this but zeros print only once but stars prints 10 time I want it to run 2nd function to run every time when the loop runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably doing something that is not intended. With

```
url = colom.xpath('//*[@id="tab-5"]/ul/li/@data-href').extract_first()
```

inside the loop, `url` always results in the same value. By default, Scrapy filters duplicate requests (see [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html?highlight=duplicate#dupefilter-class)). If you really want to scrape the same URL multiple times, you can disable the filtering on request level with `dont_filter=True` argument to `scrapy.Request` constructor. However, I think that what you really want is to go like this (only the relevant part of the code left):

```
def parse(self, response):
    Colums = response.xpath('//*[@id="tab-5"]/ul/li')
    for colom in Colums:
        url = colom.xpath('./@data-href').extract_first() 
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)
```